# Use .htaccess to only allow requests IF a header with a specific value is present

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a case where I want to protect some files (listing the directory AND accessing the content) unless a specific header is present and if that header contains the correct value.

For example if a header named "x-test-header" is present AND has a value of "abc123" then let the traffic go through, otherwise return a 403.

I have tried a variety of things such as:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_x-test-header} !^abc123
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=403,L]
```

The above works in the sense that it blocks traffic but when I use a REST client to include the header it still returns a 403.  Clearly I am not doing something correctly, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Using Apache 2.4.33 on AWS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This rule should work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-test-header} !^abc123$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Beautiful!  Besides the HTTP_ versus HTTP: in the rule what do the other differences in your response mean?  Just so I am clear on what is actually happening.  Thank you!!

Comment: Other changes are minor like `F` instead of `R=403,L` and removal of un-necessary `.*` after `^` in pattern. I also added `$` after `abc123` to make sure we only match this string